# How to set a variable in a child process in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parent-child, stdin, child-process

i´m having some troubles setting a variable in a child process with Node.JS.

My code for passing looks like this:

parent.js:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

// Run node with app.js file as argument
var child = spawn("node", ["app.js"]);

// Send data to child process via its stdin stream
child.stdin.setEncoding = "utf-8";
child.stdin.write(parseFloat("45.00").toFixed(2));

// Listen for any response from the child:
child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Got data from child: " + data);
});
```

app.js:

```
var temp;

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
process.stdin.on("readable", function(){
    temp = process.stdin.read();
    return temp;
});
```

Then a function in the child-process should set the variable temp as the Setpoint for a PID - controll:

```
ctrl.setPoint(readSetpoint());
ctrl.setInput(readInput());
ctrl.compute();

Output = parseFloat(ctrl.myOutput).toFixed(2);

function readSetpoint(){
        return temp;
    }

function readInput() {
        V = sensor.value;
        return Input = (parseFloat(fmap(V, 484, 550, 27.8, 66))).toFixed(2);
    }

 console.log("INPUT:" + Input);
 console.log("OUTPUT:" + Output);
```

When i set the variable temp = parseFloat("45.00") in app.js, the PID controll heats to 45° C but i want to set the target temperature via the parent.js.

Atm i´ll get

> Got data from child: INPUT:24.33
>
> Got data from child: OUTPUT:NaN

and the heater does not heat so i guess the Setpoint is not set.

I´m a beginner in programming so atm i´m kind of lost.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Kind regards

Comment: 1) It looks as if the string `ctrl.myOutput` is not a number, so parseFloat returns NaN. Check for a given number, for example: `Output = parseFloat("12345").toFixed(2);`

Comment: 2) Why not use `fork` instead `spawn`? And `send`? https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle

Comment: 1) ctrl.myOutput should be a number between 0 and 255, when i start app.js directly (not via parent.js) its actually working and parseFloat returns values  (the output is used to controll a mosfet with pwm).


2) Guess i´ll try that. Are there any benefits from using fork?

Comment: Are you try `Output = parseFloat("12345").toFixed(2);`? What output? If `Output = 12345`?